# Problem when I connect Crystal Reports with SQL Server not responding

Tags: c#, sql-server, crystal-reports

Can anyone help me? When I connect Crystal Reports with SQL Server, it is not responding like this screenshot:

[image]

But when I connect to SQL Server with data source, there are no problems.

Comment: Sorry, I tried to help with the English but maybe I got it wrong since you reverted it.  I'm not a Crystal Reports expert.  But, can you type a real server name in for Server?

Answer (score 0):

1. Are you trying to select the drop downs or are you just typing in the name of the database?
2. Have you tried a different server name?  Such as localhost, or the ip address of your machine?  (open cmd -> ipconfig)

If you can connect via sql server management studio, try doing @@servername to see if its a named instance instead of the default.

Comment: thanks my bro to answer me :

1) Yes after i put name sql server (.) iam select the drop down to show all data base but not responding 
-
 2) iam writing . because it's local server

Comment: and i try to select  drop down server but not responding too and not show and names for server

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `(.)` to refer to the local SQL Server instance you should use `(local)`.  You could also use the hostname of the machine that the SQL Server instance runs on.

Comment: iam try but no success